# R Packages Installation Error on Ubuntu

Tags: r

I am trying to install the R package "colorspace" in Ubuntu Linux from local repository as follows:

```
    install.packages("/home/colorspace_1.2-4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

This throws the following error:

```
Installing package into '/home/vertica/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'colorspace' ...
** package 'colorspace' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'colorspace'
* removing '/home/vertica/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/colorspace'
Warning message:
In install.packages("/home/colorspace_1.2-4.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package '/home/colorspace_1.2-4.tar.gz' had non-zero exit      
status
```

Could someone help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its saying it can't find "make", which makes me think you don't have all the compilers and so on that you need to build packages from source.

Install the "build-essential" package, something like:

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

from your command line (not from R!)